# How to stop showing plot XQuartz but in vscode?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am new to `vscode-r`, I tried `plot(rnorm(100))` and expected the plot will be shown **within** vscode; however, it is showed by XQuartz and it is outside vscode, see below:

[image]

How can I have the same outcome like the following?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `vsc.plot` option is set to `FALSE`. You can try changing it to `Two`. Here is the relevant from the [vscode-R doc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r). You need to add this option to .Rprofile file. You can easily access the file by typing `usethis::edit_r_profile()` in R console.

```
# Which view column to show the plot file on graphics update
# Use FALSE to diable plot watcher so that the default R plot device is used.
# Only specify in .Rprofile since it only takes effect on session startup.
options(vsc.plot = "Two" | "Active" | "Beside" | FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest vscode-R, I recommend that you install `{httpgd}` package and enable `r.plot.useHttpgd` in vscode settings. And then you could see plots within vscode and the plot viewer is much nicer than the default plot viewer based on png which has some known issues (e.g. no auto-adjusting of plot size, poor handling of multi-part plots and plot history).